# "Absent additional configuration"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, clauses

I have come across the following sentence but it doesn't quite sound right.

> Absent additional configuration, permits will be distributed at a fixed rate.

Is the first part of the sentence correct?

If not, then what is a good way of phrasing it?

Comment: Using *absent* like that seems common in American English, although it does not occur in standard British English. What do you intend it to mean?

Comment: *Absent* here just means *in the absence of*, *without*. In other words, if additional configuration does not occur, permits will be distributed at a fixed rate.

Comment: @onomatomaniak Do you mean it really means, or it is the intention of the writer to mean? Is the structure grammatical and popular? I think *in the absence of* is what is required.

Comment: @Kris What it really and truly means. See the prepositional definition of the word: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absent

Comment: @Kris it really means that. It is [synonymous with *without*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absent?q=absent#absent__12).

Comment: @onomatomaniak My point was that, *that* was what was needed for an answer. Your two comments complement to form the complete answer, along with additional reference from Matt Эллен

Comment: @MattЭллен Thanks. This page now has everything needed for an answer, I suppose. As is the answer from "A".

Comment: The [OED entry for *absent* prep.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/649) says that it is “orig. and chiefly U.S. Law” and means “In the absence of, without.” The latest citation is from the *Daily Telegraph* — ***not*** an American journal of jurisprudence, you will note — from 2006-03-17: “An Australian republic is not only not inevitable, but, absent some calamity, it will never come to pass.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *[absent](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absent?q=absent#absent__12)* here functions as a preposition. This is not very common in  British English but it appears to be a lot more common in American English.

> **absent** | formal, North American
>
> without: *employees could not be fired absent other evidence.*

Comment: I disagree that it is uncommon. It strikes me as a standard, perfectly acceptable usage in American English.

Comment: @A As much as it is Uncommon, is it correct?

Comment: @onomatomaniak By *not very common* I'm suggesting that it is less common in British English. Sorry. I should have clarified that.

Comment: @artfullyContrived Yes, it is correct.